# How to access compressed value of a string in zstd using c language?

Tags: python, c, compression, zstd

I novice in C. how to access compressed value of a string in zstd using c?
I know how to do it in python, for ex:

[image]

```
import zstd
import sys

#string to be compressed 
q=b'dcvlnzcndsjlffdfjldfds lfdslffnlklmgkds jsjgsnfklsgklsbfjfdflfkjsfbkhxv vnjfnvjfnfdngkjdfngkjdfkgjdfkgbkjfdgkjdgbkjfgkjfgkjfbgkfdknkjvnfkjvfvmflkvm;flmvsfforiofjreiofjeiorfsdhj'

print("compressed string is...")
w=zstd.compress(q)
print(zstd.compress(q)) 

print('')
print("decompressed string is...")
print(zstd.decompress(w))

print('')
print('decompressed size is =',sys.getsizeof(q),'compressed size is =',sys.getsizeof(w))
```

Output:

```
compressed string is...
b"(\xb5/\xfd \xb0\x85\x03\x00b\x89\x17\x14\xa0\xa5\xe9\xdf\x04\xe0\x88\xdc2\x93\x10I\x9d\xe2\xf4\x0f\xab.\x1c&h=\x8cb\x18\x0e\xd7(\x0e\xa3\xb5+\xd4@\xb9S\xcb\xf5\xfc\xd6\xf9u\xf6C\x86\xf5\xc9\xbc\xf4\xbc\xf4\xa7\xd8\xaa\xaf\xea\xba\xe0\x00\x88\x93\x9a_*\xeb\x12\xa3\x8f\xd1[66\x07\xc6O\xa1S\xb5d,\x05\xc6\x92\\\xb6dc\t\x01E'0\x05\x00O\t\xbf\xcbk\xe9\xa0se\x16\xac\x98\x01"

decompressed string is...
b'dcvlnzcndsjlffdfjldfds lfdslffnlklmgkds jsjgsnfklsgklsbfjfdflfkjsfbkhxvvnjfnvjfnfdngkjdfngkjdfkgjdfkgbkjfdgkjdgbkjfgkjfgkjfbgkfdknkjvnfkjvfvmflkvm;flmvsfforiofjreiofjeiorfsdhj'

decompressed size is = 209 compressed size is = 154 '''
```

How to do the same with c language as well?
In C I tried dictionary_compression as well as simple_compression but I'm able to access only the size not the compressed value.

Comment: "How do I use the zstd C API?" seems a bit too broad a question for SO... Start with reading the documentation?

Comment: Can you show us your C code that doesn't work, and the errors you get from it?

Comment: Have a look at [this example](https://github.com/facebook/zstd/blob/dev/examples/simple_decompression.c).